# Javascript working in IE8 but not chrome and safari and other latest browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

Following is the javascript code

```
var text;
var name;
window.onload = init;
function init() {
    var button = document.getElementById("submitButton");
    text = document.getElementById("nameTextInput");
    button.onclick = handleButtonClick;
}
function handleButtonClick() {
    if (text.value == "") {
        alert("oops !! Enter Name");
    }
    else {
        var content = document.getElementById("content");
        content.removeChild(h4);
        content.removeChild(img);
        content.removeChild(form);
        name = document.getElementById("name");
        name.innerHTML = text.value + ", I am tracking you at ";
        getMyLocation();
    }
}
```

When I click the button, the elements are removed but name div doesn't show anything. It works on IE8 but in chrome, safari and opera it falters.

Following is the HTML :-

```
<body>
<div class="topMiddle">Locate ME ;-)
</div>
<div id="content" class="content">
    <h4 id="h4">Your Name</h4>
    <img id ="img" src="rows-hand-.png" alt="arrow image" height="70" width="70" />
    <form id="form">
        <input type="text" id="nameTextInput" size="40" placeholder="Enter your name dear" class="inputTextClass">
        <input type="button" id="submitButton" value="Submit" class="inputButtonClass">
    </form>
    <div id="name" class="name">
    </div>
    <div id="user" class="user">
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="me" class="me">
    </div>
</div>
```

Following is the CSS :-

```
.content
{
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:10px;
}

h4 
{
    color: #E9E9E9;
}

.inputTextClass 
{
    width:150px;
}

.inputButtonClass
{
    margin-top:20px;
    width:80px;
}

.name
{
    color:#000;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is the online link :- http://rdinvent.com/locateMe.html

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: `content.removeChild(h4);`? Unless you defined `h4`, `img`, and `form`, it will throw error.

Comment: @JiminP , it doesn't throws error. BTW i have define them now, but still name div is empty, doesn't shows anything.

Comment: I have updated the post with the server link

Comment: @Pankaj Upadhyay Look at my edited answer. The problem is the `name` you use in your JS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

It's just this `name` which messes everything up:

```
name = document.getElementById("name");
```

Replace this line and the following with:

```
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = text.value + ", I am tracking you at ";
```

And of course, remove the `var name;` at the beginning.

`name` is a global property (window.name) and should not be used in the global scope otherwise.

Comment: but yesterday when i was working with name, it was working fine, may be i defined in the function yesterday and that's why there was no problem :P

Comment: It's not a keyword (see my answer), but you're right, that's what's messing things up here.

Comment: My bad. I ran into this issue a looooong time ago and I didn't remember everything. You're totally right. But I think that not using keywords/reserved words as variable name is still a good advice.

Answer (score 3):

This code shouldn't work, because you didn't define variables `h4`, `img` and `form`.

```
content.removeChild(h4);
content.removeChild(img);
content.removeChild(form);
```

Why it **does** work in IE8, is because IE does by default make global JavaScript variables for each element with an `id` attribute, with the same name. So `h4`, `img` and `form` are equivalent to the following code in IE.

```
h4 = document.getElementById('h4')
img = document.getElementById('img')
form = document.getElementById('form')
```

Just add this, and the code will work in the other browsers as well.

Comment: You're right about that but it's already working in Chrome (I've just jsfiddleed it).

Comment: mate i tried these var's but still name, doesn't show anything :-(

Comment: updated the post with server link [rdinvent.com/locateMe.html](http://rdinvent.com/locateMe.html) . Check here for yourself. In IE8 it shows the name entered while in other browsers , it just doesn't show up

Comment: @Pankaj Upadhyay Look at my edited answer. The problem is the `name` you use in your JS code.

Answer (score 2):

What is happening here is that you're **not** actually using your own **variable** named `name`, **but** a **property** of the **global object** `window` named `name`, so it's equivalent to using `window.name` which is a string and cannot be set to any other type (the browser forces that). So when you're setting it to the div it gets converted to a string and the string does not have a property innerHTML on it so you're setting a new property with that name which does nothing.

You can do two things:

1. You can rename your global variable `name` to something that's not in `window` object already (like `name1` or `inputName`);
2. You can put all your code inside a function and run that. This would make a new scope and your variables would override and hide the global ones.

> ```
> (function(){
>     /* your code goes here */
> })();
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Is your div "name" outside the form.

Answer (score 0):

Enable javascript in the browsers...
Check this link for reference

[Adjusting images, JavasScript, and other web content settings](http://www.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=23852)

Answer (score -1):

Not all browsers support setting `innerHTML` or `innerText` directly. What you can do is create a text-element and append as a child.

Comment: Chrome definitely allows you to set `innerHTML`. His problem is somewhere else entirely.